# unhandled exception on client machine(UWP) - how find add info?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, dump, unhandled-exception

I published my UWP(for Win10 desktop) in store. I get errors from users.
User wrote me a letter. What I have:

- I know the place where the app falls(in user). On my computer it is working(version app from store)
- I know the device and the version of the Windows (user).
- I have stack trace from Hockeyapp for this user-case:

> SharedLibrary!+0x4a0ad0
>        MyApp!+0x113b148
>        MyApp!+0x113b084 Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreA
>        pplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, 
>        ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)

This is my chance to find a problem. But what can I ask from the user? 
If on his machine there is a crash dump it is equivalent to a dump from HockeyApp?
I put a lot of effort into this application but this error is all brought to naught. Please any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest updating the app with some additional logging. You know where the problem happens so you can trace the line range where the exception occurs by adding a few log lines. For example at the beginning of the methods that are called at that point, that will help you pinpoint which method causes exception and then you can analyze it further by logging variable contents, etc.

The stack trace from HockeyApp is not really helpful as it is, so you really need more information.